# Transform AAABBB table of tensors into nested ABABAB table of tensors in Torch

Tags: machine-learning, lua, torch

I am trying to solve this problem for quite some time and still cannot come up with a solution, maybe somebody can help me out here. I have the following **AAABBB** input table to the neural network:

```
{
  1 : 
    {
      1 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x200
      2 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x200
      3 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x200
    }
  2 : 
    {
      1 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x54
      2 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x54
      3 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x54
    }
}
```

The above table gets preprocessed and then needs to be transformed into **nested** **ABABAB** input table:

```
{
  1 : 
    {
      1 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x200
      2 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x54
    }
  2 :
    {
      1 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x200
      2 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x54
    }
  3 :
    {
      1 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x200
      2 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x54        
    }
}
```

How can I transform **AAABBB** table to **ABABAB** **nested** table **within** the network using [Torch table layers](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/table.md)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that **dpnn** package contains a [Container](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/containers.md#nn.Containers) that does exactly that.
[ZipTable](https://github.com/Element-Research/dpnn#nn.ZipTable) zips a table of tables into a table of tables.

Here is a working example of how to convert **AAABBB** table into **ABABAB nested** table.

```
require 'dpnn'

aaa = torch.DoubleTensor(3,32,200)
bbb = torch.DoubleTensor(3,32,54)

model = nn.Sequential()
par = nn.ParallelTable()
par:add(nn.SplitTable(1))
par:add(nn.SplitTable(1))
model:add(par)
model:add(nn.ZipTable())
model:forward({aaa,bbb})
```